# Getting error when using jQuery to completely hide elements that are associated with jCarousel

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

I am having a tough time figuring out how to completely remove or hide an element, say a div that has jCarousel hooked with it, using jQuery. E.g.

```
<div id='featured_border' class='jcarousel-container'>  
<div id='featured_wrapper' class='jcarousel-clip'>  
<ul id='featured_images' class='jcarousel-list'>
```

I have applied effects on these elements using jcarousel. But I need to 'completely' hide these elements in response to an event, say to a click.
In response to the event, the elements do hide, but after about 3 seconds, I get this error in the alertbox:
    *jCarlousel: No width/height set for items. This will cause an infinite loop. Aborting..*

I've tried using remove() to remove the elements instead of simply hiding it,even though that is not exactly what I would love to do, but it didn't help either.

Is this some kind of a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: if you want to hide them, but keep their height and width registered with the page you should do css `visibilty:hidden`

Comment: Well that was the first thing I tried, when out-of-the-box jQuery functions didn't work for me. I tried `display:none` as well.
But nothing seems to work.